# Webpack project with mutliple html / js / css files

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I think that I've got how Webpack works. My problem is: Most tutorials/examples are based on a single `index.html`. So, how would I organize my `webpack.config.js` and directory structure for multiple pages?

Let's assume that I need the following things:

1. `index.html` with a `css` and `js` file
2. `dashboard.html` with a `css` and `js` file
3. `profile.html` with a `css` and `js` file

And here is what I don't get:

1. How would you structure your `src` and `dist` folder?
2. How do I have to configure Webpack? Probably with `HtmlWebpackPlugin`(?)
3. Is a single `index.js` file enough as entry point / How does one structure the `index.js` file / How do ES6 projects look in general?

A sample project would help a lot. A project with more than just an example `index.html` file.

Have a good day! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think u can do that by convert `html+js+css` into web component and u can do that easily by a framework , i think `Vue js` give very good boilerplate full Webpack template to let u do that just start to think about the other page as a **new component** remember that u r using webpack to get a bundle

Comment: That means, that every line of code is loaded into every *.html file? Wouldn't that be stupid? Loading loads of unused js into a light just-text.html file? :)

Comment: well `Vue js` fixed that problem, imagine that u have  a photo gallery with it's `js+css+html` and of course the `js lib` to make them work , Vue will only init the gallery when u load it as a component as new page then u can kill the gallery and delete it from memory if it has decent API so it is about init and kill to have better loads of js

Answer (score 0):

So you can have one watch output multiple bundle types by passing in a command line arg to build the right bundle.  There can be multiple entry points in webpack but webpack is only build to output one bundle.  So, to solve this issue I figured passing a command line arg to webpack is a clean way of having multiple bundle possibilities while maintaining only one config file.

To see how this can be accomplished checkout...

https://www.hipstercode.com/blog/27/